# Use eslint with @typescript-eslint/parser, but the typescript rules not work

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want to use eslint and @typescript-eslint/parser to test my ts code, but got none errors of typescript rules.

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]
}
```

./src/index.ts

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

const obj: A = {
  a: 1,
}
```

run lint, but no errors

```
eslint --ext .js,.ts ./src/index.ts
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be a lint failure, if you want to type check use the compiler. You can see the rules that are "recommended" here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin#supported-rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I check the rules in the github, but I didn't find the suitable rule, however, there are many rules in typescript, it seems not easy to enable all of them.

Comment: I'm saying there *isn't* a rule that does that; linting and type checking are two different things. It's quite easy, just use `/all` instead of `/recommended`.

Comment: Got it, but if I wanted to use both eslint & ts type check, what should I do? Now, my webpack project use both ts-loader & eslint-loader to achieve.